# numerical spherical integration

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration, quadrature

I am trying to find a numerical sperical integration methods with high precision. I have been using the numerical integration based on lebedev quadrature of 131th order.

Is there any numerical code can outperform it?

[https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/sphere_lebedev_rule/sphere_lebedev_rule.html](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/datasets/sphere_lebedev_rule/sphere_lebedev_rule.html)